# Bootstrap tooltip with complex html in Ember

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

I want to show an html list in a tooltip in an ember view.

I would like to know how a data from a template can go to a subclass component. Like...

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
      placement: "bottom",
      html: true,
      title: "<ul> {{#each groups as |group|}} <li>{{group.name}}</li> {{/each}} </ul>"
    });
  }
});
```

I know I'm completely wrong but you probably understand what I want to do.

I've tried directly in the template like

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<ul>
                                  {{#each groups as |group|}}
                                  <li>{{group.name}}</li>
                                  {{/each}}
  </ul>">{{group_count}}</a>
```

But the build fails :

```
A block may only be used inside an HTML element or another block.
Error: A block may only be used inside an HTML element or another block.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a computed property and use it as your title:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  titleComputed: Ember.computed('groups.[]', {
    get() {
      let groups = this.get('groups');
      if (!groups || groups.get('length') === 0)
      {
        return;
      }

      let result = '<ul>';
      groups.forEach(group => {
        result += '<li>' + group.get('name') + '</li>';
      });
      return result + '</ul>';
    }
  }),
  didInsertElement() {
    let title = this.get('titleComputed');
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
      placement: "bottom",
      html: true
    });
  }
});
```

And in your template

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title={{titleComputed}}>{{group_count}}</a>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @daniel-kmak. The problem with that is it only read the first groups and not each of my list. Here is a jsbin of how my datas looks like. http://emberjs.jsbin.com/hibafo/edit?html,js,output. When I `console.log(this.get('groups'));` it's seems correctly processed but the first groups is rendered on all tooltips.

Comment: edited the answer. Waiting for your feedback @daniel-kmak. It's working for me, but it's maybe a little bit strange. Why are you using get() ?

Comment: You don't have to use `get()`, you can just use normal function instead of object, but it's more clear to me when you specify computed properties with explicitly specifying that there's only getter and no setter. It doesn't matter here, it's style issue, what works for you.